# the correct use for auto &i range?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class UserData 
{
    std::string status = "Active"; 
 public:
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string get_status() //no colon
    {
        return status;
    }
};

int main()
{
  UserData user1;
  user1.first_name = "LaLaLa";
  user1.last_name = "GGGG";
  UserData user2;
  user2.first_name = "HaHaHa";
  user2.last_name = "DDDDD";


  std::vector<UserData> uservec;
  uservec.push_back(UserData());
  for (auto& i : uservec) { std::cout << i << "\t"; };
}
```

Complier keeps telling me that no operator "<<" matches these operands at line: `for (auto& i : uservec) { std::cout << i << "\t"; };`. If I create a function and make a for loop, it will be ok, but I don't know why I can't use`for (auto& i : uservec)` to read the range of`uservec`? Anyone can let me know why, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the actual variable type is `i`?  Given that answer, does C++ out-of-the-box know how to output that type using `<<`?

Comment: You can figure out that the problem isn't the loop because `std::cout << uservec[0];` gives the same result.

Comment: Or simply a two line `main` program:  `int main() { UserData u; std::cout << u; }`.  Figure out how to get that program to work, and magically your `for` loop will work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's class type vector

Comment: @Embeddeder -- *it's class type vector* -- No it isn't.  It is a reference to a `UserData`.  You are simply trying to output a `UserData`, and the compiler has no idea what it means to output a `UserData` using `<<`.  That's what the error is all about.

Comment: @chris you are right, but I don't know why I can't do this way. I'd like to know why:D

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why not. please let me know thanks.

Comment: @Embeddeder It isn't because it isn't.  A range-based for loop has on the left side of the `:` the data type of each item in the item on the right of the `:`.  What is the data type stored in the `uservec`?  If you want further proof, if you are using an IDE that shows you the type behind the `auto`, it will tell you it is a reference to `UserData`.

Comment: @Embeddeder, C++ commonly takes the stance that if the language does something for you, it covers all cases and isn't a guess at something that might be useful. When it comes to your own datatypes, some other languages cover all of them in some default `toString` implementation that often isn't what you want, but often works well enough for your purposes. In C++, you'd run into cases like including data members that aren't salient (part of the value) or have indirection (a pointer) on top of the guess at a useful format, and C++'s regular answer to that is to not even try.

Comment: As a quick example to support that statement, look at missing the return statement in a function. The language accepts it because in general, forcing a compiler to figure out whether the function can return without hitting a return statement is an undecidable ("impossible") problem. However, compilers issue a warning in almost every day-to-day occurrence of this. The language doesn't even try, but compilers do the best they reasonably can and don't promise perfection.

Comment: Thank you both, for the comments and guide me thru this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler tells you already what is missing. Your class does not have an << operator.

So, please add it and all problems are solved.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class UserData
{
    std::string status = "Active";
public:
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string get_status() //no colon
    {
        return status;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const UserData& ud) {
        return os << ud.first_name << ' ' << ud.last_name;
    }

};

int main()
{
    UserData user1;
    user1.first_name = "LaLaLa";
    user1.last_name = "GGGG";
    UserData user2;
    user2.first_name = "HaHaHa";
    user2.last_name = "DDDDD";


    std::vector<UserData> uservec;

    uservec.push_back(user1);
    uservec.push_back(user2);
    for (auto& i : uservec) { std::cout << i << '\n'; };
}
```

In the for loop `auto& i` will return a reference to a UserData element in the vector. Means, in the first loop run "i" will be "user1" and in the next loop run "i" will be "user2".

in the output part, you will then have first:

- `std::cout << user1 << '\n';` and then
- `std::cout << user2 << '\n';`

At this time the operator `<<` for your UserData will be called, because you tell the compiler to do so.

So, you use the operator `<<` for an output stream `std::ostream` (in this case `std::cout`) and "user1" of type UserData. Then the compiler knows that it needs to call this overloaded operator.

Comment: It works, but could you please explain me how `friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const UserData& ud) {
        return os << ud.first_name << ' ' << ud.last_name;` taks effect?

Comment: @Embeddeder: Please see my edited answer at the bottom under the code

Comment: One last question in your code: `return os << ud.first_name << ' ' << ud.last_name;` why do we need << ' ' <<? and how it works?